# Docusign Integration with Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

How to integrate Docusign with Asp.Net, so that a user can send a document to an authorized person or adding multiple authorized person for signature. Currently I am using the walk-through api provided by Docusign, but the problem is that the document that is sent to the authorized person is not showing any feature to add signatures or even it is not showing in its "Awaiting my Signature" section of Docusign Inbox

```
APIServiceSoapClient client = CreateAPIProxy(); 
EnvelopeStatus status = client.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope); 
if (status.SentSpecified) { 
    AddEnvelopeID(status.EnvelopeID); 
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more info for us to help you here, for starters you should post your test code.  And what do you mean by "The document is sent... but not showing any feature to add signatures"?

Comment: Hi Erign, Thanks for the response. 
Please have a look at the code below that i have taken from Docusign demo app.

APIServiceSoapClient client = CreateAPIProxy();       
EnvelopeStatus status = client.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
if (status.SentSpecified)
{
 AddEnvelopeID(status.EnvelopeID);
}

The above code is executed sucessfully, but my Signer is not recieveng any email to review the document

Comment: That's a start but still not enough, all you're showing is the CreateAndSendEnvelope() call.  We need to see the `envelope` object that you are building and passing in.  WHat does its tabs look like?  What about the recipients?  Please edit your post and add this info in.  It also woudn't hurt if you add a link showing where this code is coming from...

Comment: Thanks Erign, my problem is resolved now.

Comment: Can you please answer your own question so that the community can benefit from your solution?